# How to form clusters for VANETs using Sumo+Veins+Omnet++

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am working on a project involving spectrum sensing of VANETs. To do that, i need to specify formation of clusters and cluster heads to coordinate the whole process. 
My question is, how do i specify cluster formation? is it on the Omnet++ platform or on sumo?
I have successfully installed sumo 0.25.0, veins 4.4, and Omnet++ 4.6. and i have imported the map from openstreetmap onto sumo.

Rop.

Comment: Is "head" a vehicle or infrastructure unit?

Comment: The Cluster head is a vehicle. It is an infrastructure less scenario where vehicles/nodes choose their cluster head to coordinate spectrum sensing and other functions.

Comment: Your question is very broad and does not ask a concrete question - it seems you are asking more for a tutorial how to write models instead of help to a specific problem. For that I can recommend [the Tic Toc Tutorial](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/) and the [Veins Documentation](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases vehicle clustering in Veins happens in the application layer and therefore is completely independent from SuMO which only is responsible for the vehicle movements.

Hence, code to form clusters has to be written in OMNeT++ modules in your Veins simulation. Basically, you can put your code wherever you like, however it is nice to stick to the current project structure which would suggest to put your modules in src/veins/modules/application.

To get algorithms for forming clusters you can search the literature or come up with your own ideas which you than have to implement within the aforementioned modules. Consider the [Tic Toc Tutorial](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/) to find out how to add modules and functionality.

Comment: Thanks Julian a lot for your help. I understand how Tic Toc is modeled, will look for some literature and sample algorithms for forming clusters. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome :) If this answer helped you, please consider marking it as the solution to your problem ;-)